# Sharepoint Import-SPEnterpriseSearchCustomExtractionDictionary, is there any export function?

Tags: search

How can we export / list the Dictionary imported using the powershell `Import-SPEnterpriseSearchCustomExtractionDictionary`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploy a thesaurus

You create and maintain the thesaurus file in a file external to SharePoint 2013 before you import it into SharePoint 2013 to make the synonyms available to the search system. You can’t export a thesaurus from SharePoint 2013. If you want to make changes to your synonyms, you have to update the thesaurus file and then redeploy it.

Note:
When you redeploy a thesaurus file, the existing thesaurus will be overwritten with the information from the updated thesaurus file.

To import a thesaurus file

Verify that the user account that is performing this procedure is an administrator for the Search service application.

Start the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell.

For Windows Server 2008 R2:
On the Start menu, click All Programs, click Microsoft SharePoint 2013 Products, and then click SharePoint 2013 Management Shell.

For Windows Server 2012:
On the Start screen, click SharePoint 2013 Management Shell.

If SharePoint 2013 Management Shell is not on the Start screen:
Right-click Computer, click All apps, and then click SharePoint 2013 Management Shell.
For more information about how to interact with Windows Server 2012, see Common Management Tasks and Navigation in Windows Server 2012.

At the Windows PowerShell command prompt, type the following command:

```
$searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication 
Import-SPEnterpriseSearchThesaurus -SearchApplication $searchApp -Filename <Path>
```

---

```
 $searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication

 Import-SPEnterpriseSearchCustomExtractionDictionary –SearchApplication $searchApp –Filename <Path> –DictionaryName <Dictionary name>
```